# How to do perform push operation to get the filename inside comments

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Am finding values from db

```
app.get('/getcoments',isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
console.log("comments dfsd")
mongo.filemanager.find({comments : {$exists:true}, $where:'this.comments.length>0'},{file_name:1,comments:1,},function(err,response){
    if(err) throw err  

    response.forEach(function(values){

      console.log(values)
    })

})

});
```

Am getting following output:

```
resume_of_ganga_.docx
{
  created_date: 2017-11-28T13:23:51.472Z,
  status: 'N',
  comment_text: 'Yes...',
  username: 'name' }
```

I want to include the filename inside the comment .. How to do that

Comment: Can you show us the exact output you want to get? I don't quite understand

Comment: Thanks for your response,I fixed my issue by using push